# Is there any straightforward way to send a message to MSMQ inside SP in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, msmq

Is there any way to send message to MSMQ from a stored procedure in SQL Server other than running Windows command line code, or external assembly, or all this complex workarounds? I mean more native and straightforward way.

Comment: I don't expect so, unless you call SQL/CLR native.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sp_OAmethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174984) to invoke [`MSMQMessage.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See [Message Queuing COM Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [OLE Automation Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190501).

Are you sure [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) cannot fit the bill, does the destination *have* to be MSMQ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion regarding MSMQMessage.Send, I'll check it up. Finally I need the message to reach MSMQ anyway, Service Broker might be just intermediate in the flow. I'm not very good at Service Broker however, know too little about it

Comment: If your final destination is MSMQ then use MSMQ from the get go.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but does this work?  I've seen conflicting information about using sp_OAmethod where the varaible type is a VARIANT, which MSMQMessage.Send uses....